# My JavaScript doesn't run properly in shared sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm new to work with JavaScript. I create a Google Sheet and a script. The script works fine for me.

But when I share the sheet, the script just works in the active cell when the other user runs the script of my sheet.

The user authorize the script. I don't understand why the function `onEdit` is having trouble with shared sheet.

Any solution?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ActiveRow = ActiveSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var ActiveCell = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (email == "a@gmail.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#ff0066");
  }}
```

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` is returning a blank string most likely because the onEdit function doesn't require the user's authorisation. Do some research on  [`getActiveUser()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())